# EF Core 7 Task Cancellation exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, entity-framework-core, cancellation-token

I have a piece code written in an ASP Core 7 API, with EF Core 7, using MSSQL for the database. The below code is where the repository loads some data for the dashboard.

```
public async Task<ResponseResult<DashboardPendingBillsDto>> PendingBillDetails(CancellationToken token)
{
    var venderInvoicelQuery = _context.Set<VendorInvoice>().AsQueryable();

    var pendingBillsQuery = venderInvoicelQuery.Where(a => !a.IsBilled);

    var today = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    var fourthDay = today.AddDays(-3);
    var seventhDay = today.AddDays(-7);

    var pendingBillsData = await pendingBillsQuery.Select(s => new
    {
        BetweenOneToFiveDays = pendingBillsQuery
            .Where(a => fourthDay.Date < a.CreatedOn.Date && a.CreatedOn.Date <= today.Date).Count(),
        BetweenSixToTenDays = pendingBillsQuery
            .Where(a => seventhDay.Date < a.CreatedOn.Date && a.CreatedOn.Date <= fourthDay.Date).Count(),
        AboveTenDays = pendingBillsQuery
            .Where(a => a.CreatedOn.Date <= seventhDay.Date).Count()
    }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(token);

    var dashboardPendingBillsDto = new DashboardPendingBillsDto
    {
        BetweenZeroToThreeDays = pendingBillsData?.BetweenOneToFiveDays ?? 0,
        BetweenFourToSevenDays = pendingBillsData?.BetweenSixToTenDays ?? 0,
        AboveSevenDays = pendingBillsData?.AboveTenDays ?? 0,
    };

    return new ResponseResult<DashboardPendingBillsDto>(dashboardPendingBillsDto);
}
```

The above code returns the desired data as well as shown below

[image]

The problem is, if the HTTP request was cancelled, then the `TaskCanceledException` exception is thrown and it gives an error `An error occurred using the connection to database 'test-db-12-jan-2023' on server 'DESKTOP-xxx`. But i already passed the cancelation token into the `FirstOrDefaultAsync(token)` as such. it happens only if the http request was cancelled. Any help please.

**update 29-jan-2023**

I have a middle ware to handle exceptions globally and it is the first middle ware of the pipeline

[image]

And here is how the middleware handles the exceptions. i have only 2 exceptions here, `TaskCanceledException` and `Exception`

```
private Task ConvertException(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        var activityId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? "N/A";

        _telemetry.TrackException(exception);

        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new() { TraceId = activityId };

        int httpStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        var result = string.Empty;

        switch (exception)
        {
            case TaskCanceledException:
                //if client closes the connection
                httpStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
                result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ResponseResult<string>("Client closed the connecion"));
                break;
            case Exception:
                httpStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
                errorResponse.Errors.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>(nameof(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError), new[] { "Something went wrong, please try again" }));
                result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorResponse);
                LogError(exception, activityId);
                break;
        }

        context.Response.StatusCode = httpStatusCode;

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
```

Below is the exception message i get from the middleware

```
A task was cancelled
```

Below is the the stack trace from the exception which i can get from the middleware

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenInternalAsync>d__70.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenInternalAsync>d__70.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenAsync>d__66.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<InitializeReaderAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
   at VPMS.Persistence.Repositories.Dashboard.DashboardRepository.<PendingBillDetails>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Legacy HealthCare - Vendor Payment Management System\VPMS\VPMS.Persistence\Repositories\DashboardRepository\DashboardRepository.cs:line 162
   at VPMS.Application.DashBoard.Services.DashboardService.<GetPendingBillsAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Legacy HealthCare - Vendor Payment Management System\VPMS\VPMS.Application\DashBoard\Services\DashboardService.cs:line 25
   at VPMS.Api.Controllers.Dashboard.DashboardController.<GetPendingBills>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Legacy HealthCare - Vendor Payment Management System\VPMS\VPMS.Api\Controllers\DashBoardController.cs:line 30
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.<Execute>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
   at VPMS.Api.Middleware.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Legacy HealthCare - Vendor Payment Management System\VPMS\VPMS.Api\Middleware\ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 25
```

But i have serilogged configured and it gives an exception which does not hit the middle ware which is the real problem in here which is

`An error occurred using the connection to database 'test-db-12-jan-2023' on server 'DESKTOP-xxx`

The above error message is logged to the serilog but it never reaches the middleware and this is the exception i want to avoid. this is the problem here.

Comment: That is the expected behavior. If you cancel a CancellationToken (aborting the request), the TaskCanceledException is thrown. Just handle the TaskCanceledException.

Comment: its already handled, it works for other queryies, only this query throws the error

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is above... You're showing a stack trace - presumably of TaskCanceledException, and that's it. As @thanzeel wrote above, the exception itself is expected, and there's nothing in the above code that shows you handling it.

Comment: hi @ShayRojansky, i have updated the question. i have added custom middle ware the handle exceptions globally. i have added more info the question above. please read till the end.  hope you can help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you asking why an exception doesn't make it to your middleware? I can't really tell - you're probably catching it somewhere before that, without bubbling it up... Either way that's not really directly related to cancellation or EF.

Comment: BTW I'd recommend catching OperationCanceledException rather than the narrower TaskCanceledException (the latter extends the former). But ultimately you need to follow the code flow in your program to understand exactly what happens with the exception, to understand why it doesn't reach the middleware.

Comment: @ShayRojansky, im not asking why the exception is not hitting the global exception handler,  rather the exception thats says `An error occurred using the connection to database 'test-db-12-jan-2023' on server 'DESKTOP-xxx` is thrown from ef core even though the cancellation token is used.

Comment: @ShayRojansky, and i have not written any try catch block anywhere in the code, so all exception will bubble upto the exception handling middle ware. i tried wrapping the repository method with try catch, but still the `An error occurred using the connection to database 'test-db-12-jan-2023' on server 'DESKTOP-xxx` is not caught

Comment: @ShayRojansky, i have been trying to get the stack track but all i could get is this `{"EventId":{"Id":20004,"Name":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection.ConnectionError"},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection","ActionId":"a8e3ba46-7b24-4277-be30-381401d65f41","ActionName":"VPMS.Api.Controllers.Dashboard.DashboardController.GetFinancialLevelBillApproverWise (VPMS.Api)","R22:14:48.396 +05:30 [ERR] An error occurred using the connection to database 'vpms-test-db-12-jan-2023' on server 'DESKTOP-48015B1'.`

Comment: Are you saying that you're triggering the cancellation token, but the exception that gets thrown isn't an OperationCanceledException? If so, what is the *type* of that exception (you haven't posted that above)?

Comment: @ShayRojansky, one excpetion i can catch is the TaskCancelledExption, thats not an issue i have managed it in the code. the second exception does not get caught anywhere in the app. the second exception, which logs `An error occurred using the connection to database 'test-db-12-jan-2023' on server 'DESKTOP-xxx`  in the serilog does not get caught anywhere in the exception handlers. if i comment the ef call to the db, then the second exception does not occur.

Comment: What's the type of the second exception?

Comment: @ShayRojansky, thats the problem, i cannot get the type of the second exception since it doesnt not hit any of my try catch block or the global exception handler.

Comment: Serilog should be logging the full exception details, no?

Comment: @ShayRojansky, serilog only logs this line `An error occurred using the connection to database 'test-db-12-jan-2023' on server 'DESKTOP-xxx` and nothing else

Comment: @ShayRojansky ,after debugging the serilog, i followd the call stack and the error has orgininated from `namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.Internal;` from the method  `ConnectionError()` and thengoes to `LogConnectionError()` and then `ShouldLog()` and from there it logs ` [ERR] An error occurred using the connection to database 'vpms-test-db-12-jan-2023' on server 'DESKTOP-xxxx'` since the task has been cancelled `(A Task was canceelled)`. the exception is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection.ConnectionError[2004]`. why would it do this?

Comment: Are you using EnableRetryOnFailure? If so, you may want to try disabling it to make sure the exception gets thrown by EF. Otherwise, I'm not aware of any situation where EF would log such an error but not throw an exception; I'd check once again that you're not swalloing it somewhere, and if you're sure you're not, try to put together a minimal repro for this.

Comment: @ShayRojansky ,im not swallowing the exception anywhere in the entire code base. im not using `EnableRetryOnFailure` as well. i will try to put on a minimal repo. thanks